# Replacing values in same column and same dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
Name|Material |Project  
John|LS       |222  
Jack|Limestone|111  
Job |LI       |121
```

I want to replace LS and LI with Limestone in Materials column.
I have tried this for LS:

```
ds$Material[ds$material %in% grep("^LS^",ds$Material,ignore.case = TRUE)]<-"Limestone"
```

But the column still has a bunch of LS in there. Any ideas?

Comment: Replace the second `^` with a `$`.

Comment: @JensLeerssen still a bunch of LS

Comment: `ds$Materials[ds$materials %in% c("LS", "LI")] <- "Limestone"` ?

Comment: @Uwe tried it, still no joy.

Comment: You need to dput your data into the question. There could be trailing white space in your vector, or other issues we can't detect without the data

Comment: That are simply typos: `ds$Material[ds$Material %in% c("LS", "LI")] <- "Limestone"`

Comment: Downvoted?Really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `gsub()` to replace `LI` and `LS` with `Limestone`:

```
ds$Material <- gsub("LS|LI", "Limestone", ds$Material)
#   Name Materials Project
# 1 John Limestone     222
# 2 Jack Limestone     111
# 3  Job Limestone     121
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe

```
ds <- 
    read.table(text = "Name Material Project
                        John LS        222  
                        Jack Limestone 111  
                        Job  LI        121  
                      ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

> ```
> > ds
>   Name  Material Project
> 1 John        LS     222
> 2 Jack Limestone     111
> 3  Job        LI     121
> ```

Subsetting the column where only `LS` is found.

```
ds$Material[grep("^L[SI]$", ds$Material, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Limestone"
```

Result

> ```
> > ds
>   Name  Material Project
> 1 John Limestone     222
> 2 Jack Limestone     111
> 3  Job        LI     121
> ```

In dplyr:

```
ds %>% mutate(Materials = gsub("L[SI]", "Limestone", Materials))
```

Comment: Note that your question has a column `Material` not `Materials` (note the trailing "s")

Comment: @Uwe the above is mock data. I fixed it. Thanks for mentioning it though

Comment: @uwe Thanks for the poke. I had adjusted the example to match his code, instead of the other way around. All is now aligned to his original dataframe example.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
df <- tibble(Name = c("John", "Jack", "Job"), Material = c("LS", "Limestone", "LI"), Project = c(222, 111, 121))

df %>% mutate(Material = stringr::str_trim(Material)) %>%  
        mutate(Material = case_when(
                              Material %in% c('LS', 'LI') ~ 'Limestone',
                              TRUE ~ Material
                              )
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can use `ifelse`.

```
# Reproducible example
data <- read.table(textConnection("Name|Material |Project  
                                   John|LS       |222  
                                   Jack|Limestone|111  
                                   Job |LI       |121  "),
                   sep = "|", row.names = NULL, header = TRUE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
data$Material <- ifelse(data$Material %in% c("LS", "LI"), "Limestone", data$Material)
```